# How to match multiple column values with multiple rows from other table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables table1, table2. Now table1 has 3 columns id,col1,col2 with vales as "V1" and "V2". table2 has 2 columns (t1,t2) with t2 contains multiple values like "V1", "V2", "V3", etc. Now I want to fetch rows from table1 if both col1 and col2 have matching values from table2 of t2 column.

**table1**

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V1 | V2 |
| 2 | V2 | V4 |

**table2**

| t1 | t2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | V1 |
| 2 | V2 |
| 3 | V3 |

From the above 2 tables, only id 1 of table1 will be fetched since col1 and col2 has values that are matching with table2. I like this condition to be invoked. I have tried several ways but couldn't find out exact solutions. Can anyone help please?

Comment: So only the `t2` value from the second table is relevant, and the `t1` isn't?

Comment: yes only t2 is relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by joining `table2` twice:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 table2_1 ON table1.col1 = table2_1.t2
INNER JOIN table2 table2_2 ON table1.col2 = table2_2.t2
```

Note that this assumes `t2` is unique in table2.  If that is not the case, you'll need to add a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Is it possible to fetch all the rows from table1 like for table1, since row 2 has 1 column mismatch, so, can I create a extra column and show like "V4 is not matching"?

Comment: Sure.  Just change the `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s and add a couple of columns: `IF(table2_1.t2 IS NULL, CONCAT(col1, ' is not matching'), NULL) AS col1_check, IF(table2_2.t2 IS NULL, CONCAT(col2, ' is not matching'), NULL) AS col2_check`

Comment: I used this code but it's showing NULL under column (col1_check, and  col2_check) for both the rows of table1

Comment: Yes, now the code worked. Thanks Rob!!! Best answer so far.